# Cannot install vscode update 1.86.1 /1.86.2 on Debian 10

Tags: debian

When trying to install update 1.86.1 or 1.86.2 over 1.85.2 on my Debian 10 I get this message:

Dependency is not satisfiable: libxkbfile1 (>= 1:1.1.0)

I've updated and updagred my system and force the installation of libxkbfile1 (>= 1:1.1.0)

sudo apt update
sudo apt aupgrade
sudo apt install libxkbfile1

and I got:

Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
libxkbfile1 ya está en su versión más reciente **(1:1.0.9-2+b11)**.
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 1 no actualizados.

It says libxkbfile1 is already in its most recent version (1:1.0.9-2+b11). What can I do?

I always install vscode with:

sudo gdebi code_1.86.2-1707854558_amd64.deb